# Matplotlib figure is not updating with ipywidgets slider

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization, ipywidgets

I have the following code to generate a simple graph.

```
%matplotlib notebook
from ipywidgets import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))

def update(w = 1.0):
    line.set_ydata(np.sin(w * x))
    plt.show()

interact(update)
```

The code generates the plot just fine -
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISKPw.png)

But when I drag the slider, the figure will not update. Any ideas on why this is?

Answer (score 4):

Note: Your code actually works for me out of the box, so it may be worth updating your dependencies and see if that fixes it.

However, the main thing you want to change is to call `fig.canvas.draw()` instead of `plt.show()`

```py
%matplotlib notebook
from ipywidgets import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))

def update(w = 1.0):
    line.set_ydata(np.sin(w * x))
    fig.canvas.draw()

interact(update)
```

#### Using Ipympl

There is also a widget based notebook backend (that will also work in jupyterlab): [ipympl](https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl) which you can install with `pip install ipympl` and use with `%matplotlib ipympl`

In general the ipympl backend will work better with other widgets than the notebook backend.

#### using `interactive` with matplotlib

One unfortunate consequence of `interactive` is that it assumes the output will be fully regenerated every time the slider value changes. This doesn't always play super nicely with the `set_data` methods you are using. So you are likely better off manually generating and connecting the sliders. I'll also note that I've written a package that automates using the `set_data` command to connect widgets to updating matplotlib plots: https://mpl-interactions.readthedocs.io/en/stable/. With that package your code would be

```py
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_interactions.ipyplot as iplt

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 1000)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

def f(x, w):
    return np.sin(w * x)

controls = iplt.plot(x, f, w=(1, 10))
```

Comment: The `mpl_interactions` package is absolutely fantastic. Solved double (even triple) display issues and it's lightning fast. Great work!

Answer (score 0):

This would do a job.

```py
# load the interactive tool
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, widgets, fixed
try:
    from ipywidgets import Layout
except:
    pass 

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook

def fta(freq = 50.0):
    "showing sine frequency"
    y = np.sin(freq*x)
    f, ax1 = plt.subplots(nrows=1,figsize=(8,6))
    ax1.plot(x[0:100], y[0:100],'b')
    ax1.set_ylim(ymin=-1.1, ymax=1.1)
    ax1.grid();
    # then use it interactively,
interactive( fta, freq=(0.0,100.0))
```

[image: interactiveplot]

Comment: The issue with this approach is that it will create a new figure on every change without closing them, leading to high memory usage and warnings about too many open figures quickly. Also `%matplotlib notebook` seems to be outdated, and the code seems to contain unnecessary dead imports.