# refresh matplotlib in Jupyter when updating with ipywidget

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, ipywidgets

I want to draw a line in a Jupyter notebook, which can be moved using an ipywidget slider. I also want to have the mouse coordinates displayed, for which I'm using `%matplotlib notebook`. Here is what I have so far :

```
%matplotlib notebook
from ipywidgets import interact


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

@interact(n=(-200, 0))
def show(n):
    # fig.clear() #doesn't show anything
    y = -n+x
    ax.plot(x, y)
    
    plt.show()
```

When moving the line using the slider, the plot doesn't refresh, all previous positions of the line
remain visible:
[image]

I tried to refresh using `fig.clear()`, but then noting shows.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an extensive answer about this here: [Matplotlib figure is not updating with ipywidgets slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66004177/matplotlib-figure-is-not-updating-with-ipywidgets-slider/66067877#66067877)

but the short of my recommendations are:

1. use [ipympl](https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl#ipympl) `%matplotlib ipympl` instead of `notebook` as this will play nicer with ipywidgets
2. Use [mpl-interactions](https://mpl-interactions.readthedocs.io) to handle making plots controlled by sliders.

   - It will do the optimal thing of using `set_data` for you rather than clearing and replotting the lines.
   - It also interprets the shorthand for numbers in a way that (I think) makes more sense when making plots (e.g. using linspace instead of arange) see https://mpl-interactions.readthedocs.io/en/stable/comparison.html for more details.

So for your example I recommend doing:

install libraries

```
pip install ipympl mpl-interactions
```

```py
%matplotlib ipympl
from ipywidgets import interact
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_interactions import ipyplot as iplt

x = np.linspace(0,100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def y(x, n):
    return x - n
ctrls = iplt.plot(x, y, n=(-200,0))
```

it got a bit longer because I added the imports you left out of your question  and also defined x.

Which gives you this:

### [image: gif of mouse interacting with slider and line updates]

That said if you don't want to use those I think what you want is `ax.cla()` I think when you do `fig.clear` you are also removing the axes which is why nothing shows up.

```py
%matplotlib notebook
from ipywidgets import interact


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

@interact(n=(-200, 0))
def show(n):
    y = -n+x
    ax.cla()
    ax.plot(x, y)

    plt.show()
```

Comment: `ax.cla()` doesn't seem to clear the figure, but your solution based on `mpl_interactions` works great. And `ipympl` is much more fluid than standard `notebook`. Thanks.